# analyze time complexity for this short code

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, bubble-sort

I'm trying to evaluate runtime complexity for these few lines of code, this is a bubble sort code.
now I know it's O(n^2) but I wanna do an accurate analysis. 
and I'm not sure I'm getting it right

```
for i ← 1 to n-1
    for j ← n downto i+1
      if A[j-1] > A[j]
          temp ← A[j-1]
          A[j-1] ← A[j]
          A[j] ← temp
```

what I did was : 
first line is executed n times, so (c1)*n
the second line depends on i, but it'll be n, then n-1, ..., 1 
and that's where my problem is , should I use summation over i? seems weird that the runtime is dependent of i
third line is also dependent of the array we're getting, and the next lines are dependent of that.

can anyone help with a proper analysis ?
thanks ahead .

Comment: The outer loop will be executed `n-1` times; the inner loop will be executed approximately `n/2` times (forget `i`, it's just distracting you), and the block of code executed inside the `if` statement is just that, a block that is going to be executed about `k(n-1)(n/2)` times, where `k` is a fraction which is not dependent on `n`.  Hence `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

For every value of `i` the code performs a number of operations that depends on `i`, say `c(i)`. So the total amount of operations would be

```
total := sum_{i=1}^{n-1} c(i)
```

Let's now compute `c(i)` for a generic `i`. In the worst case the true branch of the `if` statement is always executed and takes, say, `C` operations, which is a quantity independent from `j`, `i` and `n`. So

```
c(i) <= sum_{j=n}^{i+1} C
      = C*(n - (i+1) + 1)
      = C*(n - i)
```

Thus

```
total <= sum_{i=1}^{n-1} C*(n-i)
       = C * sum_{i=1}{n-1} (n-i)
       = C * n(n-1)/2
       = O(n^2)
```

Note that in the best case, the true branch of the `if` will never happen and you will only have to take the number of operations needed to compute the inequality, say `D`. Therefore, you can repeat the same calculation as before replacing `C` with `D` and `<=` with `>=` to get

```
total >= O(n^2)
```